# What is the area of triangle ABC?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, polynomials, area

Verbatim my Math test-

Consider a polynomial $y=P(x)$ of the least degree passing through $A(-1,1)$ and whose graph has two points of inflexion $B(1,2)$, and $C$ with abscissa 0, at which, the curve is inclined to the positive axis of the abscissa at an angle $arcsec(\sqrt {2})$.

Find the area of triangle ABC.

Any help?

Comment: If you knew $P(0)$, then finding the area would be mechanical. A grind it out way to find $P(0)$ is to identify the polynomial. There are $5$ items of information provided, so the least degree polynomial is probably a quartic. We can easily get a lot of information about the first three coefficients by using the inflection point stuff. Another easy target is that the derivative at $x=0$ is $1$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, agreed, and I would say $P$ is definitely a quartic because $P$ is a polynomial of least degree with two inflection points.  A polynomial with two inflection points in general must be at least quartic (because its 2nd derivative must be at least quadratic).

Comment: @AndréNicolas, that's a rather clever way at looking at the problem, I must say. I'll keep that in mind, the next time I solve something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know if this is the quickest/easiest/best/etc. way but here's one way..

$P$ has two inflection points, which means $P''(x)$ has two distinct real zeros.  Therefore $P''(x)$ has degree at least 2, which means $P(x)$ has degree at least 4.  Since $P(x)$ is a polynomial of least degree, we can conclude that $P(x)$ must have degree 4.  Therefore we can say $$ P(x) = ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e,$$

where $a, b, c, d, e \in \Bbb{R}$ such that $a \ne 0$.

Then we have: $$P''(x) = 12ax^2 + 6bx + 2c $$

We are told there are two points of inflection, i.e., two points where $P''(x) = 0$.  They are $(1,2)$ and some other point with $x$-coordinate (that's what "abscissa" means in case anyone reading this doesn't know) equal to 0.  So then $$ P''(1) = 12a + 6b + 2c = 0 $$ and $$ P''(0) = 2c = 0.$$

This last line above tells that $c = 0$.  Hooray!  Therefore we have $$P(x) = ax^4 + bx^3 + dx + e.$$

Also, we can use $c = 0$ simplify the $P''(1) = 0$ equation to get $$ P''(1) = 12a + 6b = 0.$$

This equation tells us that $b = -2a$.  So then we have $$P(x) = ax^4 - 2ax^3 + dx + e.$$

We are told that the graph of $P$ passes through $(-1,1)$.  Therefore, $P(-1) = 1$, and we have $ a + 2a - d + e = 1$, which simplifies to $$3a - d + e = 1.$$

Also, $P$ has a point of inflection at $(1,2)$.  This means $(1,2)$ must be a point on the graph.  Therefore $P(1) = 2$, which gives us $a - 2a + d + e = 2$, which simplifies to $$-a + d + e = 2.$$

There's one piece of information we haven't used yet:

> ...abscissa 0, at which, the curve is inclined to the positive axis of the abscissa at an angle $arcsec(\sqrt {2})$.

I'm interpreting this to mean the angle between the positive $x$-axis and the tangent line to the graph of $P$ at $x = 0$ is $\sec^{-1} \sqrt{2} = \pi/4$.  What is the equation of the line that goes through the origin and makes an angle of $\pi/4$ with the positive $x$-axis?  It's the line $y = x$.  You can use polar coordinates and say the equation of this line is $\theta = \pi/4$, and then convert to rectangular coordinates by using $\theta = \arctan(y/x)$.  Then you get $\arctan(y/x) = \pi/4$, and so $y/x = \tan(\pi/4) = 1$, giving us $y = x$.

Anyway, the equation of the tangent line to the graph of $P$ at $x = 0$ is $y=x$, and  this line has slope $1$.  Therefore the graph of $P$ also has slope $1$ when $x = 0$.  In other words, $P'(0) = 1$.  Recall that $$ P(x) = ax^4 - 2ax^3 + dx + e.$$  Therefore $$ P'(x) = 4ax^3 - 6ax^2 + d,$$ and so we have $$P'(0) = d = 1.$$

So far we have $P(x) = ax^4 - 2ax^2 + x + e$.  Recall our two equations from earlier: $3a-d+e = 1$ and $-a+d+e = 2$.  Now we have $d = 1$, so these two equations become $3a + e = 2$ and $-a+e = 1$.

Solve this system of equations to find $a$ and $e$, which will completely determine $P(x)$.  Then evaluate $P(0)$ to find the $y$-coordinate of the point $C$.  Then you'll have the coordinates of the vertices of $\triangle ABC$, and from there it's a routine geometry problem to find the area.

Comment: It makes things more pleasant to note at the beginning that $P'(0)=1$, so $d=1$ and then $d$ need not take part in the equations.

Comment: @tilper, that's a great solution! I hadn't deduced the equation was bi-quadratic.

Comment: Very nice! The only suggestion I might make is that since what we really want is the slope of the tangent at $x=0$ it’s not necessary to find the angle explicitly. We have $\sec\theta=\sqrt2$, so $m=\tan\theta = \sqrt{\sec^2\theta-1} = \sqrt{2-1}=1$.